# KeyError: 'view' when rendering document_view

Tags: plone, upgrade

Migration from 2.5 to 3.3.5.  I inherited a plone system that we have to migrate to 3.3.5 to keep the site accredited.  I know zilch about plone and come from primarily a windows administration, sharepoint and .net programming background.

I feel like I'm so close to having this working.

When I navigate to a page, the page comes up with an error code instead of content (improvement over having the traceback show up instead of the page).  The error is now this:

```
Exception traceback
Time    2012/09/19 11:24:04.160 GMT-7
User Name (User Id) Anonymous User (None)
Request URL http://localhost:8080/mission-vision/index_html/document_view

Exception Type  KeyError
Exception Value 'view'
Traceback (innermost last): 
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 119, in publish 
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 88, in mapply 
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 42, in call_object 
Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 313, in __call__ 
Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 350, in _bindAndExec 
Module Products.PageTemplates.ZopePageTemplate, line 330, in _exec 
Module Products.PageTemplates.ZopePageTemplate, line 427, in pt_render 
Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplate, line 98, in pt_render 
Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 117, in pt_render 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__ 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 891, in do_useMacro 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 957, in do_defineSlot 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 861, in do_defineMacro 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 949, in do_defineSlot 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 861, in do_defineMacro 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 891, in do_useMacro 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 534, in do_optTag_tal 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret 
Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 745, in do_insertStructure_tal 
Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 223, in evaluateStructure 
Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
URL: file:d:\websites\nipo\plone 3.3.5\buildout-cache\eggs\plone-3.3.5-py2.4.egg\Products\CMFPlone\skins\plone_deprecated\document_actions.pt
Line 27, Column 4
Expression: <StringExpr u'plone.documentactions'>
Names:
{'container': <PloneSite at /Plone>,
 'context': <ATDocument at /Plone/mission-vision/index_html>,
 'default': <object object at 0x010BD528>,
 'here': <ATDocument at /Plone/mission-vision/index_html>,
 'loop': {},
 'nothing': None,
 'options': {'args': ()},
 'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x04A37B98>,
 'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:8080/mission-vision/index_html/document_view>,
 'root': <Application at >,
 'template': <ZopePageTemplate at /Plone/document_view used for /Plone/mission-vision/index_html>,
 'traverse_subpath': [],
 'user': <SpecialUser 'Anonymous User'>}
Module Products.Five.browser.providerexpression, line 17, in __call__
KeyError: 'view'
```

It looks like the problem is in the document_view template.  Which is odd because it hasn't been modified at all, it's straight out of the box:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
      xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
      xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
      xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
      lang="en"
      metal:use-macro="here/main_template/macros/master"
      i18n:domain="plone">
<body>

<metal:main fill-slot="main">
    <tal:main-macro metal:define-macro="main"
           tal:define="kssClassesView context/@@kss_field_decorator_view;
                       getKssClasses nocall:kssClassesView/getKssClassesInlineEditable;
                       templateId template/getId;
                       text here/getText;">

        <div tal:replace="structure provider:plone.abovecontenttitle" />

        <h1 class="documentFirstHeading"> 
            <metal:field use-macro="python:here.widget('title', mode='view')">
            Title
            </metal:field>
        </h1>

        <div tal:replace="structure provider:plone.belowcontenttitle" />

        <p class="documentDescription">
            <metal:field use-macro="python:here.widget('description', mode='view')">
            Description
            </metal:field>
        </p>

        <div tal:replace="structure provider:plone.abovecontentbody" />

        <p tal:condition="python: not text and is_editable"
           i18n:translate="no_body_text"
           class="discreet">
            This item does not have any body text, click the edit tab to change it.
        </p>

        <metal:field use-macro="python:here.widget('text', mode='view')">
        Body text
        </metal:field>

        <div metal:use-macro="here/document_relateditems/macros/relatedItems">
            show related items if they exist
        </div>

        <div tal:replace="structure provider:plone.belowcontentbody" />

    </tal:main-macro>
</metal:main>

</body>
</html>
```

Anyone know why this is coming up?

Comment: It's not the document_view template that's at fault here, something is going wrong with the viewlet rendering (the `plone.documentactions` viewlet manager is being rendered). Not sure why `view` is not there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how do I see that?  How can I modify it?